# Avoid code duplication at test level with Util class

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testing, code-duplication

I've got a Java project in Maven with the following (simplified) structure:

```
module-alpha
    src
        main
        test
            java
                TestUtils.java <-----------------------
module-beta
    src
        main
        test
            java
                TestUtils.java <-----------------------
...
module-yotta
    src
        main
        test
            java
                TestUtils.java <-----------------------
```

There is a class `TestUtils.java` repeating itself along the project. (It's a simple class I wrote as a library for needed stuff in every unit test.)

How can I avoid this code redundancy?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a different maven project that include `TestUtils.java` and build it as a jar e.g. test.jar.

Then use test.jar as a [local dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352732/best-way-to-add-local-dependency-to-maven-project) of relevant projects.

Comment: Awesome, but one question: Where should I place that test.jar to be found by Maven? (Sorry for the basic question, I've never do this before.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352732/best-way-to-add-local-dependency-to-maven-project